# pyqt - Change row~cell color in TableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, tableview, background-color

I have a QTableView with three columns
The second column is about numbers, there are only three types: 1, -1 and 0.
I want to have different colors for this three "types" of numbers (1,-1,0), coloring their rows with different colors. How can i do it?

```
 self.tableView = QTableView(self.tabSentimento)
 self.tableView.setGeometry(QRect(550,10,510,700))
 self.tableView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("TabelaSentimento"))
 self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
 self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

obs: I used `horizontalheader().setStrechLastSection(True)` because I opened an existing csv file (using a button) into my tableview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define the color in the model, not in the view:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    ...
    if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
        return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
```

**Edit:**
Here's a working example, except for the color part completely stolen from http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/06/pyqt-42-qabstracttablemodelqtableview/

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

my_array = [['00','01','02'],
            ['10','11','12'],
            ['20','21','22']]

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

class MyWindow(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QTableView.__init__(self, *args)

        tablemodel = MyTableModel(my_array, self)
        self.setModel(tablemodel)

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, datain, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.arraydata = datain

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()
        # vvvv this is the magic part
        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if index.row() % 2 == 0:
                return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
            else:
                return QBrush(Qt.red)
        # ^^^^ this is the magic part
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        return QVariant(self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: ..First, thank you. But, can you give me a example? like creating a tableview with two lines with diferent colors? i am trying but i never did something like this.

Comment: i have another question about colors, but now using a button to color a table with existing data.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666635/pyqt-put-color-in-a-qtableview-with-existing-data