# pyqt - put color in a QTableView with existing data

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, tableview

i need help to color my QTableView. @rainer helped me putting color when i  initialize a table, but now, i already have a table with data(but without color// my data is a csv opened in my table), and i want to create a button that when clicked it colors the tableview in some lines,  like when there is  a row with -2 (data), it will be color with blue color.. 
-- I have a button and a table. This button load the csv data into my tableview. I want to have a new button that color the rows of this table. ( but color only rows that have -2 of data, for example)
Some codes:

```
    self.fileName = (_fromUtf8('tweets.csv'))
    self.tableView = QTableView(self.tabSentimento)
    self.tableView.setGeometry(QRect(550,10,510,700))
    self.tableView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("TabelaSentimento"))
    self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

    self.pushButtonLoad = QPushButton(self.tabSentimento)
    self.pushButtonLoad.setGeometry(QRect(550,720,130,30))
    self.pushButtonLoad.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonLoadCSV"))
    self.pushButtonLoad.setText(QApplication.translate("Form", "Process!", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButtonLoad.setStyleSheet('color:red;background-color:rgb(255, 255, 153);border:1px solid purple;')
    self.pushButtonLoad.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonLoad_clicked)


    def loadCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, "rb") as fileInput:
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):    
                items = [
                    QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
            ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)

    def on_pushButtonLoad_clicked(self):
        print self.fileName
        self.loadCsv(self.fileName)
```

Comment: `QStandardItem` has a method `setBackground()` which you can use to set its background color: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#setBackground. So, when your second button is clicked, simply iterate over all rows and set the color accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could for example subclass the model and reimplement the `data` method, this code example will change the cells background color to blue if the `pushButtonColorize` is checked and the value of the cell is equal to 1. It will also affect cells in the same row.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

import random
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyStandardItemModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    _colorize = False
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyStandardItemModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def setColorized(self, state):
        self._colorize = state

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundColorRole \
        and not self._colorize:
            return QtGui.QBrush()

        return super(MyStandardItemModel, self).data(index, role)

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pushButtonColorize = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonColorize.setText("Colorize Cells!")
        self.pushButtonColorize.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButtonColorize.toggled.connect(self.on_pushButtonColorize_toggled)

        self.pushButtonReload = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonReload.setText("Reload Data!")
        self.pushButtonReload.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonReload_clicked)

        self.modelSource = MyStandardItemModel(self)

        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.modelSource)

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonReload)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonColorize)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.tableView)

        self.pushButtonReload.click()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonReload_clicked(self):
        self.modelSource.clear()

        for rowNumber in range(3):
            items = []
            for columnNumber in range(3):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                item.setText(str(random.getrandbits(1)))

                items.append(item)

            self.modelSource.appendRow(items)

        if self.pushButtonColorize.isChecked():
            self.on_pushButtonColorize_toggled(True)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_pushButtonColorize_toggled(self, state):
        self.modelSource.setColorized(state)

        rowCount    = self.modelSource.rowCount()
        columnCount = self.modelSource.columnCount()

        for rowNumber in range(rowCount):
            for columnNumber in range(columnCount):
                cellIndex = self.modelSource.index(rowNumber, columnNumber)
                cellData  = self.modelSource.data(cellIndex, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

                if str(cellData).isdigit() \
                and int(cellData) == 1:
                    for cellColumn in range(columnCount):
                        self.modelSource.setData(
                            self.modelSource.index(rowNumber, cellColumn),
                            QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.blue),
                            QtCore.Qt.BackgroundColorRole
                        )

        self.modelSource.endResetModel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.resize(333, 222)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but if i want to change the color for the full cell?
Like for a column with -1, all cell = blue.. for column with 0, all cell = red (for example)...Im having many  problems like this: ttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newProgram.py", line 37, in data
    if (cellData).isdigit()\And many problems like this : File "newProgram.py", line 37, in data if str(cellData).isdigit() \ nicodeEncodeError:'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 72-79: ordinal not in range(128)
i am opening a csv intomytable

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand your first part of the question... Is that different colors for different values? As for the second part, the errors you are getting are probably due to the encoding of your data, you'll have to convert it to the proper encoding first.

Comment: The first part: When i use the button, i change only the color for the number but i want to change the color for all cell where this number is inserted. for example,  i have a matrix M[3,3], in (1,3)(2,3)(3,3) there are numbers, only in this places. but if i have -1 in (1,3) i want to change the color for (1,2) and (1,1) too, with the same color for (1,3). like a complete background for the row

Comment: @Marco Checkout my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15668928/1006989), I modified it to change the color for all the cells in that row.

Comment: i have another question, please, if u can, look it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285729/pyqt-how-to-change-combobox-data-because-of-another-combobox-data