# PyQt Tableview background color based on text value rather than True or False

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Follow up to [my general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101143/pyqt-tableview-row-background-colour-based-on-cell-value/44104745#44104745), where [@eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) has kindly answered my question.

Out of curiosity, I tried changing to code to check against a string rather than 1 and all the rows turned gray.

Original code from [@eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc):

```
def data(self, item, role):
    if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
        if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, self.index(item.row(), 3), Qt.DisplayRole):
            return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if item.column() == 3:
            return True if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, item, Qt.DisplayRole) == 1 else False
    return QSqlQueryModel.data(self, item, role)
```

If I change it to

```
def data(self, item, role):
    if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
        if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, self.index(item.row(), 2), Qt.DisplayRole):
            return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if item.column() == 2:
            return True if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, item, Qt.DisplayRole) == 'Young' else False
    return QSqlQueryModel.data(self, item, role)
```

then all the rows turn yellow.

What gives? Will anyone help me understand?

N.B. I'm aware that a non-empty python string will be equivalent to True

N.B. I can replicate the desired behaviour by adding another column to the SQL query (using CASE WHEN etc.) and then using setColumnHidden(col, True) to hide the test column.

Comment: Which column is the data you want to paint?

Comment: Continuing the example you wrote, assume I wanted to test `lastname == "Young"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the condition inside `if role == Qt.BackgroundRole`

```
def data(self, item, role):
    if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
        if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, self.index(item.row(), 2), Qt.DisplayRole) == "Young":
            return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if item.column() == 3:
            return True if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, item, Qt.DisplayRole) == 1 else False
    return QSqlQueryModel.data(self, item, role)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, I know it is an old subject, but just a quick question.I see you are creating a custom class, is this a requirement? That is every time we use roles do we need to subclass or can we just create a method inside or current class?Hope my question makes sense...

Comment: @Heliomaster I do not understand you, explain yourself better.

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, thanks for coming back to me. My question is lets say I have my main class like so:                                                                                             `class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Lmt.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.LmtDb = LmtDataBase()` etc... could i add the data method inside this one or do I have to create a custom class and the work with roles inside this one. Hope this makes more sense...

Comment: @Heliomaster okay, I understand what you point out, I gave the solution in a context but I see that it is inappropriate for your case, when you have time I will show you another option more simple and adaptable for your case with the help of a delegate.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. Very much willing to see how you do it. On a side note great job with your posts in general ,i’ve used a few of your examples on other subjects and they are always clear, concise and well documented. That’s what stack overflow is all about....

Comment: how to color only if clicked on the row cell