# Setting Pyqt4 TableWidget background Colour based on certain value loaded from Sqlite Database

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am trying to set  background color of TableWidget based on certain value from data loaded from Sqlite database like in example below . I have seen  below answer in [PyQt Tableview background color based on text value rather than True or False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121172/pyqt-tableview-background-color-based-on-text-value-rather-than-true-or-false)   which works .

Problem is , In my setup I use TableWidget with a Button ( I used Qt Designer )  that loads the data from Sqlite database  and  I am not too sure how to implement below code into my setup  as I dont entirely understand how it works:

```
def data(self, item, role):
    if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
        if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, self.index(item.row(), 2), Qt.DisplayRole) == "Young":
            return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if item.column() == 3:
            return True if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, item, Qt.DisplayRole) == 1 else False
    return QSqlQueryModel.data(self, item, role)
```

Below is my code for selecting and displaying Sqlite Data to TableWidget . I am using PyQT4 , Pyhton 2.7 .

```
self.load_btn.clicked.connect(self.loadData)

def loadData(self):

    ##DB Connection ###

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = "SELECT * FROM Tadata"
    cursor.execute(query)
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    for row_number, row_data in enumerate(results):
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number, data in enumerate (row_data):

            self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number,column_number,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```

Database used is sqlite . 4 rows and 4 columns .Column headers : Number , Company, Equipment , Status . 'Status' records comprises of 'YES' or 'NO' . So wherever 'NO' is , I wish for background to be red

My Table in database

[image]

tableview colour based on certain value

[image]

Comment: this method only works with QTableView, QTableWidget can not be established a new model, for your case I need you to tell me how is your table in the database

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for promt response .

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for promt response !  Database used is sqlite . 4 rows and 4 columns .Column headers : Number , Company, Equipment , Status . 'Status' records comprises of 'YES' or 'NO' . So wherever 'NO' is , I wish for background to be red .

Comment: Edit your question and add it there

Comment: Check my solution, I recommend using option 2, it is more versatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the post that samples is only valid if you use `QTableView`, `QTableWidget` does not allow to establish a new model, there are several options to solve this problem.

For the example I will assume that the data has the following form:

```
Number      Company     Equipment   Status    
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           company1    Equipment1  YES       
2           company2    Equipment2  NO        
3           company3    Equipmen3   NO        
4           company4    Equipment4  YES
```

- Using the `setBackground()` method of `QTableWidgetItem`

---

```
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
for row_number, row_data in enumerate(results):
    self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
    for column_number, data in enumerate (row_data):
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number,column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        if column_number == 3 and data == "NO":
            [self.tableWidget.item(row_number, c).setBackground(Qt.red) for c in range(len(row_data))]
```

- Using a delegate:

---

```
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        ix = index.model().index(index.row(), 3)
        if ix.data() == "NO":
            painter.fillRect(option.rect,Qt.red)
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

[...]
self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(Delegate(self.tableWidget))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I used the setBackground() method of QTableWidgetItem but there is no background color . How or where would i add the code using delegate method ?

Comment: @user3890023 The delegate establishes in the constructor. If you still have problems share my code and I add it.

Comment: Thank you so much . I must have made a typing error with option 1 . It worked with youre option 1 which I'm happy with . Thank you very much . Much appreciated !!!