# PyQt Tableview background color based on numeric values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

There is a nice example of how to achieve ["PyQt Tableview background color based on text value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121172/pyqt-tableview-background-color-based-on-text-value-rather-than-true-or-false)
since I am not allowed to comment I have to open a new question.

How can I compare column "id" as integer numbers? e.g. if (id>103) and (id<106)?

Code line taken from link above:

```
if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, self.index(item.row(), 2), Qt.DisplayRole) == "Young":
```

seems to work fine for text, but

```
if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, self.index(item.row(), 0), Qt.DisplayRole) > "103":
```

would compare as text not as integer, and

```
if QSqlQueryModel.data(self, self.index(item.row(), 0), Qt.DisplayRole).toInt() > 103:
```

gives an
AttributeError: 'QVariant' object has no attribute 'toInt'

How to compare cell values as integer, float, boolean, ...?

Comment: What version of PyQt5 are you using?

Comment: I am using PyQt5 version 5.10 on Win7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `value()` method of `QVariant` and if casting is necessary.

```
val = QSqlQueryModel.data(self, self.index(item.row(), 0), Qt.DisplayRole)
if int(val.value()) > 102:
    return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
```

Comment: thanks a lot @eyllanesc, I was mislead by the QVariant methods toInt(), toFloat(), toBool(), ...